# Is fast sync the reason why my ethereum wallet doesn't show the ether I got back through the DAO withdraw?

Tags: go-ethereum, the-dao

On block-explorers like ethersan.io I can see that the DAO withdraw worked and that ether was returned to my address. However my Ethereum Wallet (0.84 - Mac OSX using geth-node) shows my old balance.

Before I made the withdraw I used fast-sync to download the blockchain. I heard that the node doesn't know about the "state". Might this be the reason the shown balance is not correct?

Answer (score 1):

Fast sync should not make a difference to your DAO withdrawn balance. While the intermediate state is omitted in the fast sync, your balances and transactions will all be in the blockchain.

I'm assuming that your balance in etherscan.io is correct. What I would check next:

1. Is your `geth` node fully synced? If not, your recent balance changes will not be reflected in your Ethereum Wallet.
2. Is your `geth` node synced to the ETH chain and not the ETC chain? In etherscan.io, does the most recent block number correspond to the latest `eth.blockNumber` in `geth`?

Comment: The node is not fully synced. Sorry, I ought to have checked that first. It is five days behind and it is not updating anymore. I doesnt load a single block.

Comment: Have you got the latest Ethereum Wallet or `geth` installed? The newest version will fix some of the stalling issues with the syncing.

Comment: I seem to have the newest version Ethereum Wallet 0.8.4 and geth 0.14 Thank you for the help

Comment: There is a later version of `geth` v 1.4.17 but this has not been packaged with Ethereum Wallet yet. In the meantime, you will just have to wait for the syncing to complete. It will take some time to process the recent blocks with the spam transaction attacks that have been happening over the last 3 weeks.

Comment: I installed the ethereum wallet on another computer. The new install managed to fully sync! I transfered the keystore to the new install and could access all funds. The old install still seems to be completely stuck. Thanks for the help.